# Limits of Elasticsearch dynamic mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

We have been using Elasticsearch [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) feature for flexibility with our indexing.

Our top-level fields are fixed and we can essentially set `dynamic: strict` at this level ([ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html)), but we have a custom metadata JSON field, which could be nested and the field names can be arbitrary. What started as a mapping with about 100 fields in custom meta data (with nesting) three years ago has now grown to over 2000 fields now.

I don't foresee a lot of new fields in the near future, but want to understand the implication. The default number of fields for defining new mappings is 1000, so I am wondering if more than 2000 fields is really pushing the limits already. What are the limits here and how to monitor and control this?

Comment: I am not aware of a limitation. Maybe there is one (in the form of an array limit of some sort), but that is so large that it's difficult to reach it. But, with so many fields, the question is how many of these fields do actually have values in documents? Better said, are they sparse or not? Stuff to read about sparsity [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/general-recommendations.html#sparsity) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/minimize-index-storage-size-elasticsearch-6-0).

Comment: And some more from [one of the ES developers](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/maximum-number-of-fields-in-an-index-mapping/90150/2).